# Trying to understand for() and while() loops

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, break

I need help finishing the code for a school assignment:

> Make a menu that the user can choose from and allow them to select
>   which loop practice option to run. The following loop will run forever
>   until the user enters an exit option int choice;
>
> ```
> while(true) { 
>     System.out.println(“Please enter in a choice, 0 to quit”); 
>     choice = input.nextInt(); //assumes a Scanner object has been created 
>     if (choice == 0) {
>         break; 
>     } 
> }
> ```

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Christmas3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
        int on,tw;
        System.out.println("Enter 1 to execute loop one, 2 to execute loop two or 3 to exit");
        on = one.nextInt();
        while (on == 1) {
            System.out.println("Please enter 1 to confirm the loop or 0 to exit"); 
            tw = one.nextInt(); 
            if (tw == 0) {
                break; 
            }
        }
        for(int i = 0; on > i; on++) {
            System.out.print(" "+on + ", "); 
        } 
        while (on == 2) { 
            System.out.println("Please enter 2 to confirm the loop or 0 to exit"); 
            tw = one.nextInt(); 
            if (tw == 0) {
                break; 
            }
            for(int j = 0; on > j; on = on + 10){
                System.out.print(" " + on  + ", "); 
            }

            if (on == 3) {
                break;
            }
        }
        one.close();
    }
}
```

I don't know how to do the following part **"The following loop will run forever until the user enters an exit option int choice;"**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void printMyInstructions()
{
    System.out.println("Enter 1 to execute loop one, 2 to execute loop two or 3 to exit");

}

public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner myInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    int userChoice = -1 , exitChoice = 3;
    while( userChoice != exitChoice )
    {
        printMyInstructions();
        userChoice = myInput.nextInt();
        analyzeChoice( userChoice );
    }
}

public static void analyzeChoice( int enteredUserChoice )
{
    if( enteredUserChoice == 1 )
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    else if( enteredUserChoice == 2 )
    {
        // Do Something
    }
    else if( enteredUserChoice == 3 )
    {
        System.out.println("Bye Bye");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Can't really tell what to do with this Option: " + enteredUserChoice);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Loops {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (;;) {
            System.out.println("\nMain: Enter 1 to execute loop one, 2 to execute loop two or 3 to exit");
            switch (input.nextInt()) {
            case 1:
                for (boolean loopExit = false;!loopExit;) {
                    System.out.println("Loop 1: Please enter 1 to confirm the loop or 0 to exit"); 
                    switch (input.nextInt()) {
                    case 0:
                        loopExit = true;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Loop 1: Confirmed!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Loop 1: ?Unrecognized input");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Exited loop 1");
                break;
            case 2:
                for (boolean loopExit = false;!loopExit;) {
                    System.out.println("Loop 2: Please enter 1 to confirm the loop or 0 to exit"); 
                    switch (input.nextInt()) {
                    case 0:
                        loopExit = true;
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        System.out.println("Loop 2: Confirmed!");
                        break;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Loop 2: ?Unrecognized input");
                        break;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Exited loop 2");
                break;
            case 3:
                input.close();
                System.exit(-1);
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("?Unrecognized input");
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```